# Java multithreading program

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

My task is to create a program which have:

- Class `Client`
- Class `Gate`
- Class `Museum`

The `Client` enters and leaving the `Museum` by using the `Gate` class. The museum can have a maximum of 5 clients at one time.

When I input let's say 1000 `Clients` at some time, the output gives me unwanted numbers.

Sample output:

---

```
Client (358) is leaving the Museum!   number of customers: 2
Client (214) is entering the Museum!   number of customers: 3
Client (214) is leaving the Museum!   number of customers: 2
Client (73) is entering the Museum!   number of customers: 5
Client (73) is leaving the Museum!   number of customers: 5
Client (397) is entering the Museum!   number of customers: 5
Client (76) is entering the Museum!   number of customers: 6
----------------------------------------------------------------
Client (930) is entering the Museum!   number of customers: 7
Client (930) is leaving the Museum!   number of customers: 6
Client (308) is entering the Museum!   number of customers: 6
Client (183) is entering the Museum!   number of customers: 6
Client (183) is leaving the Museum!   number of customers: 5
----------------------------------------------------------------
Client (647) is entering the Museum!   number of customers: 7
Client (647) is leaving the Museum!   number of customers: 6
----------------------------------------------------------------
Client (540) is entering the Museum!   number of customers: 7
```

---

I'm expecting that the Clients are going to try to enter at some random time, and when there are 5 or more Clients in the Museum, they will have to wait for other thread to end it's task.

Here is my code:

---

## Client.java

```
package client;

import gate.Gate;
import museum.Museum;

import java.util.Random;

public class Client extends Thread {
    private static int id = 0;
    private int clientID;

    public Client() {
        Client.id++;
        this.clientID = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.enterMuseum();
        this.leaveMuseum();
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    private void enterMuseum() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(401) + 100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        while (true) {
            if (Gate.atomCustomer.get() < 5) {
                Museum.getGate(0).enter(this);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void leaveMuseum() {
        Museum.getGate(1).exit(this);
    }

    public int getClientId() {
        return this.clientID;
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

---

## Gate.java

```
package gate;

import client.Client;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Gate {
    public static AtomicInteger atomCustomer = new AtomicInteger();

    public Gate() {
    }

    public void enter(Client client) {
        if (atomCustomer.get() > 5) {
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------");
        }
        atomCustomer.incrementAndGet();

        System.out.println("Client (" + client.getClientId() + ") is entering the Museum!" +
                "   number of customers: " + atomCustomer.get());
    }

    public void exit(Client client) {
        atomCustomer.decrementAndGet();
        System.out.println("Client (" + client.getClientId() + ") is leaving the Museum!" +
                "   number of customers: " + atomCustomer.get());
    }
}
```

---

## Museum.java

```
package museum;

import gate.Gate;

public class Museum {
    private static Gate[] gate = new Gate[2];

    public Museum() {
        gate[0] = new Gate();
        gate[1] = new Gate();
    }

    public static Gate getGate(final int numberOfGate) {
        return Museum.gate[numberOfGate];
    }
}
```

---

## ApplicationTest.java

```
import client.Client;
import museum.Museum;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ApplicationTest implements Runnable {
    private static int NUMBER_OF_CLIENTS = 0;
    private static ArrayList<Client> listOfClients;
    private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new ApplicationTest()).start();
    }


    private static void init() {
        while (NUMBER_OF_CLIENTS < 5) {
            System.out.println("How many clients?( > 5): ");
            NUMBER_OF_CLIENTS = sc.nextInt();
        }

        listOfClients = new ArrayList<>(NUMBER_OF_CLIENTS);
        new Museum();

        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CLIENTS; i++) {
            ApplicationTest.listOfClients.add(new Client());
        }
        for (Client c : listOfClients) {
            c.start();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        ApplicationTest.init();
    }
}
```

---

I will be grateful for any help. Thanks for your time. Q.

Comment: You're defeating the purpose of atomics by checking them then modifying them. Use #incrementAndGet (aka `++i`) or #getAndIncrement (aka `i++`), which will modify and _retrieve_ the value in the same operation. Otherwise you end up seeing a 4, and someone else sees a 4, and then you both increment it

Comment: Also on a personal level: never, ever, use a public static and non-final variable. Any combination of the two is suspect, all three is almost always a terrible design flaw

Comment: I've tried using a simple `int` variable, but the output was giving me an unwanted lines.

Comment: right, you'll have the same problem using `int` because increment operations on non-`volatile` primitives are not atomic (at a lower level it's actually akin to three instructions aka "methods"). This means you can have a race condition like I mentioned above within the same line. In your case it's because you did #get, _then_ #getAndIncrement. This gap in operations is where the race conditions occur. Have you read up the javadoc for `AtomicInteger`?

Comment: I've used it, because our professor told us to use it. My bad. Will read now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few suggestions, do not use public static variables and static methods like museum.getGate() or the atomic customer counter (it makes harder to understand who uses what). Also, the Client class should be completely isolated from the "counter" logic; that is, the client should simply call gate.enter(), and the access checks should be done in either Gate or Museum.

Then there is the "critical" part, where you try to assign a "permit" to clients, in

```
 while (true) {
   if (Gate.atomCustomer.get() < 5) {
     //use museum.tryEnter() instead..
     Museum.getGate(0).enter(this);
     break;
   }
 }
```

Here, if two threads call get() *at the same time*, they will both find that the number of customers is eg. 4, and they will both enter (concurrency issue).

One way to make sure only one client gets the permit is to add a nested call to some synchronized method like

```
private synchronized boolean tryEnter() {
    if (counter<5) {
        counter++;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But a better way to assign permits would be to use a Semaphore (so that you don't even need that busy loop). https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html